# How to stop tar from archiving the root path to files?

Tags: linux, unix, tar

When I run the following command:

```
tar cfvz backup.tar.gz /path/to/my/files/*
```

It gzips the entire path. So when I unzip the file, I have to go open 4 folders (path -> to -> my -> files) to get to the files I wanted to backup.

How do I make the files show in root of the gzipped file rather then the entire path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried: 
`cd /path/to/my/files` and then
`tar czvf backup.tgz *`

Comment: The `--strip-components` option while un-taring would also help. Other than that, `tar` doesn't offer you much… `cd` ing to the path you want to backup would be the only quick solution that comes to mind.

Comment: @cfreire @slhck Can't believe I didn't think of `cd`....Thanks so much!

Comment: @cfreire, slhck would one of you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try option `-C`:

`tar cvzf backup.tar.gz -C /path/to/my/files/ .`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is in a script so try something like...

```
pushd /path/to/my/files
tar cfvz backup.tar.gz *
popd
```

Tar will only include the path specified on the command-line.